# MVC in yii: how to build pages with several actions belonging to different models

Tags: model-view-controller, yii

I would like to know how you should write website pages that use for example 3 models and several actions on them.

Because there is usually only a controller involved with a page call and only a special action.

For example:
there should be a page which displays a group of people, and on that page I can edit the peoples names and assign new people to the group and i can add people as new managers of a group.
Does this page need its own controller or how do I program such pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions can belong only to controllers. In each action you can work with any models of your application. In your case you must create a UserController and a list of actions (e.g. actionViewList, actionEdit, actionAssignToGroup).
Check this for more information: [Yii Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller)

Answer (score 1):

Using your scenario, here is how I would set things up:

The controller you'd use for all related actions would be 'Group' (in Yii, 'ControllerGroup')

For your main page that displays the group of people, you could make an action in your Group controller called 'manage' (in Yii, the method name would be actionManage).  Assuming you aren't going an Ajax route, for each person on the manage page you may have a link to edit that person.  The links would point to the 'update' action.  For adding, you'd want an action 'add'.

Your models involved would likely be User, Group, and UserGroup and you'd use them as necessary in any controller you have.